# The use of Zero Value as Missing Values and Outliers

Tags: dataset, exploratory-data-analysis

I am not sure what is the best title for this question. Sorry for that.

Let's say I analyzing a **dataset of prices of houses**. And one of the columns (features) is `year_of_renovation`. Since, not every house was ever renovated, a good portion of them has `zero value` in this field.

**Personally, I considered the `zero` value to be a missing value `N.A.`. Is that correct?**

I do so because I believe columns such this one could actually be broken down into two columns, `was_renovated`, and `year_of_renovation`. Of course we don't need to break the information into these two columns, but these could be considered two different kind of information. Right?

I guess there are two scenarios:

**Scenario 1**

Having `zero` values in `year_of_renovation` means the house was never renovated. Therefore `zero` values are not `missing values`, in a first thought as `N.A` is.

**Scenario 2**

Having `zero value` meaning that the `year_of_renovation` is unknown. In this scenario, it seems that `zero values` are inter-exchanged/means the as as `N.A.` values, right?

---

Regardless of considering `zero` values the same as missing values or not, I have another two questions.

2. Would it be wrong to consider `zero` values as outliers?
3. Can `zero` values, when used to represent missing values (such as max_int, min_int ...), be also considered outliers?

Answer (score 1):

When zero is a valid value for a variable (i.e., not missing) then use it in the analysis.   However, for home price, when zero is replaced for price since it's missing, delete the zeroes, since most software will recognize the missing fields as missing.  You don't ever want to (e.g.) calculate average house price by including home with price values of zero, since it will artificially lower the average - and that it not a true average based on houses that didn't have a missing price.

The other problem you will learn when zero is used for missing is that it will often result in a large spike at zero in a histogram for a variable.

In summary, if zero truly represents something, then use it.  It could be an outlier quite easily.  You might report e.g. average and s.d. for renovation  of homes that were renovated, and then list the number of homes that weren't renovated, since all the remaining homes that were renovated will have renovation costs much larger.

Zero values that are true are usually not an outlier if the range of values falls in e.g. [0,1], [0,2] or [-2,2].  When non-zero values are large however, like home renovation costs, I would not use the zero values, and would just say for example there were 30 homes that weren't renovated (zero), and then give the average and s.d. of renovation costs for homes that were renovated for which the cost is non-zero.

Comment: I am a bit confused still, so given `zero` values in the field `year_of_renovation`. Without imply any change on the dataset, only for the sake of learning discussion, are those `zero` values considered missing data? Are those values considered outliers?

Comment: If there's a zero for a date value (year), it has to mean there was no date, or it was unknown.  Zero does not represent anything for "year," so I wouldn't use those zeroes for this field (variable).

Comment: Your latest comment (year_of_renovation) is like asking someone" What's your year_of_birth?   They respond "0".   You know that's not true, so if the zero is in a database for year_of_renovation, you no it wasn't renovated.  A bigger part of the picture you are missing is that for missing values or using 0 for year_of_renovation, those values are supposed to be set to blanks in an Excel sheet, i.e., nothing.

Comment: Also, for the question about "...you don't know if a zero means unknown year of renovation, or the home was not renovated."  This is actually your problem, as you need to contact the producer of the data and ask them how to interpret zeroes.  They made an error by using 0 in the field without providing a "Data Dictionary", which defines coding instructions (what each value represents, which should include what a zero means for each variable)